Scala can't find imported file from same directory
I'm fairly new to scala, having troubles compiling my code. So I have a project structure like this
topdir/
 com/
  name/
   final/
    file1.scala
    file2.scala

Both files are in the same package with package com.name.final In file1.scala, I want to import everything from file2.scala, with import com.name.final.file2._
However, when I run scalac file1.scala, it gives me the following error:
value file2 is not a member of com.name.final

I don't understand exactly why is this error happening, since I've followed a tutorial on packaging in scala, yet it still throws an error.

The file names are not part of the packages and imports, you don't even need to import at all in this case. Everything defined in file2 should be accessible in file1

You don't import files, you import classes from packages or an entire package. On top of that, if the files refer to same package, there's no import to declare, code in a package already has access to any code in the same package without the need for an import declaration.
